# Expected : End of statement

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with below code:
getting error in line no 1 because of " quotation mark.

```
Range("L2").Formula = "=IF(D2="Demand Open",Networkdays(U2,Today())," - ")"
Set R = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set R = Intersect(R.EntireRow, Range("L:L"))
R.FillDown
Range("L:L").Value = Range("L:L").Value
```

Comment: Asked about a million times already. :) Double up the quotes in the formula: `"=IF(D2=""Demand Open"",Networkdays(U2,Today()),"" - "")"`

Answer (score 1):

*Should be double `""`*

> ```
> Range("L2").Formula = "=IF(D2=""Demand Open"",Networkdays(U2,Today()),"" - "")"
> ```

Comment: small thing make big difference... Thanks working fine

Comment: @neerajdhiman indeed, please remember to make the answer if it helped